# CSS not recognizing class and changing content within the header

Tags: html, css, magento

[Product display that I am trying to manipulate in CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpa4q.png) using `ul, ol .row`

Megamenu `<ol>` contents are changing with my `<ul>` cms tags [Header View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfuFy.png)

```css
ul,
ol .col-3 {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: medium;
}

.col-3 {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

.col-12 {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button {
  transition: all .3s;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 40px;
  border: solid;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="size-25"><a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/razer-series.html"><span style="color: #007dbd;">Razer</span></a></h3>
      <div class="col-content" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3%;">
        <a href="https://df239c5e7e.nxcli.net/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/razer-series.html"><img src="https://casterdepot.com/media/Shepherd/RZ03TPP090SWTP05.png" alt="" width="200px;" height="250px;"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-content" style="text-align: left; padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3%;">
        <ul>
          <li>Dynamic Capacity</li>
          <li>Bearing / Raceways</li>
          <li>Finish</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="https://df239c5e7e.nxcli.net/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/razer-series.html">
          <button class="button 3" type="button">Read More</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `ul`, `ol` elements to only respond to the body content rather than stuff in the `header`. It is enlarging the content in the header because it uses a `<ol>` tag. This website is running on **Magento 2.4.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out the header was using a basic `ul`, `ol` styling so I changed the class name to `.bullet-info`. The header was overruling my styles so I had to give the bullets a custom class.

```css
.bullet-info {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: left;
}

.product-display .col-content {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -ms-box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
  padding: 0 1rem 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 .5rem .5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.product-display .row {
  max-width: 1360px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.series-text {
  margin-top: .5rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.product-name {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .series-text {
    margin-top: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .product-name {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-content">
  <ul class="bullet-info">
    <li>Dynamic Capacity</li>
    <li>Bearing / Raceways</li>
    <li>Finish</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="https://df239c5e7e.nxcli.net/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/razer-series.html">
    <button class="cd-button" type="button">Read More</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the body class before the defined ul/ol CSS

Example:

```
BODY_CLASS ul, BODY_CLASS ol .col-3 {
   margin-top: 0rem;
   margin-bottom: 1rem;
   font-size: medium;
}
```

In case the `<body>` tag doesn't has a class then you can use `body` in place of `BODY_CLASS`